# Trouble with latin characters renaming file extension from txt to xml (ASP.NET + SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: asp.net, xml, character-encoding, windows-server-2008

I have an ASP.NET web app running on a W2003 Server normally. The app copies a `.txt` file from a remote machine to the server. Afterwards the process rename the `.txt` file to `.xml`.

The problem has come when I tried to install the web in a W2008 R2 Server. Suddenly every latin character included in the `.txt` is not showing properly.

```
.txt -><TO>COMPROBACION CAMPAÑA</TO>
.xml -><TO>COMPROBACION CAMPA�A</TO>
```

My ASP.NET *Globalization* is set to *False*.

The Windows Server Language is Spanish in both servers (2003 and 2008).

Could anyone tell me what else can be?

Comment: The problem is not the renaming itself, but the use of the `Ñ`. I guess your software is working with an internal character encoding which does not support these characters. Try to print such a character on your screen just to see what happens.

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the rename?

Comment: ´With FTPConex .RemoteFile = ftpDiaElec & Format(FechaIter, "yy_MM_dd") & ".txt" .LocalFile = sDir & "\" & Format(FechaIter, "yyyyMMdd") & "_user.xml" Try .Download() While .Idle = False .DoEvents() End While QuitaNulos(.LocalFile) Catch ex As Exception Grabalog("CargaXML : Error : " & ex.Message) CompruebaFicheroDescargado(.LocalFile, CodTerminal) End Try End With´  Then problem is that the showing code is working on W2003 Server

Comment: Does anybody knows which windows server 2008 setting could change the text file encoding? The file is encoded in ANSI format but when I copy it to the server and then rename it the file is UTF8!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that the problem was reading the remote host file.

The old method

```
Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader(Fich, "ISO-8851", True))
```

The new method

```
Dim stream_reader As New StreamReader(Fich, Encoding.Default, True))
```

Now the xml file keeps the origin encoding. Nippey was right.

Thanks.